# openssl_encrypt() And openssl_decrypt() Returns 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, openssl

I am using CodeIgniter and I found this encrypt/decrypt function on the internet:

On my controller: (please read my comments)

```
    public function encrypt_decrypt( $string, $action = 'e' )
    { 
        $secret_key = 'the_secret_key';
        $secret_iv = 'the_secret_iv';

        $output = false;
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key = hash( 'sha256', $secret_key );
        $iv = substr( hash( 'sha256', $secret_iv ), 0, 16 );

        // when I die(); in this area, above codes seems fine..

        if( $action == 'e' ) { // Encrypt
            $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv ) );
        }
        else if( $action == 'd' ){ // Decrypt
            $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $string ), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv );
        }

        // but when I die(); in this area, it returns 502 Bad Gateway,  
        // maybe there's something wrong with openssl_encrypt/openssl_decrypt

        return $output;

    }
```

It works fine on my local but returns **502 Bad Gateway** error on my remote server.

Both servers have **openssl** support enabled.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what version of CI are you using?

Comment: @Vickel CI version is  3.1.10

Comment: since you using CI framework, why aren't you taking advantage of its [encryption library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html)? anyway, AFAIK the encryption key for AES-256 needs a key length of 32bytes